# Input/output error using Python module SMBus, Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, ioerror

I have connected a Raspberry Pi and a separate board together with a homemade I²C level shifter, and installed the Python module SMBus, the Raspberry Pi can communicate with the the PiGlow on the other board, but every so often I get an input/output error message when trying the command:

> bus.write_i2c_block_data(address, signal, data)

It says:

> IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error

I found a work around for it through this post: [Input/output error using Python module SMBus, a Raspberry Pi and an Arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245235/input-output-error-using-python-module-smbus-a-raspberry-pi-and-an-arduino)  (and this is more or less a follow up to that question)

I currently have try-catch's around the calls that gave me the error like so:

```
try:
    bus.write_i2c_block_data(address, signal, data)
except IOError:
    subprocess.call(['i2cdetect', '-y', '1'])
```

which works perfectly fine to work around the i/o errors.  My problem is, due to all the try-catch's, the code seems to run significantly slower.  I was wondering if there was another known work around of if there was a more efficient way to do this.  Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you call `Serial.print` or similar in the reception interrupt handler of your `separate board`? If yes, it may be the problem. On an `Arduino`, for example, one should avoid calling `Serial.xxx` functions inside an interruption.

Removing `Serial.print` lines on Arduino solved the problem for me.

Thanks.